# intersection of sets who are in the collection of sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let F be the set of all sigma-algebras containing c. then show that intersection of g where g is an element of F is also a sigma algebra.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $I$ denote the intersection. Certainly, $I \subseteq F$.

Write down what you need to prove that $I$ is a $\Sigma$-algebra. Each of the items will need to be proved using the fact that all elements of $I$ are elements of $F$ as well, and it must be true in $F$.

Can you add more work to your question and I will be happy to add further hints if needed?

Comment: Let F = set of all sigma algebras containing c.  show that ∩g is also a sigma algebra where gϵF . Also ∩g will be the minimal sigma algebra containing c.

Comment: @Rath what are the requirements for a collection of sets to be a $\Sigma$-algebra? Can you show that $\cap g$ in your case satisfies these requirements?